# Filter collection in Kotlin with existing java.util.Predicate instance

Tags: java, kotlin, filter, collections, predicate

I want to filter a collection of values in Kotlin using an instance of a java.util.Predicate implementation, basically something like this:

```
val predicate = JsQueryPredicate<SportEvent>(query)
schedule.sport_events.filter(predicate)
```

This doesn't compile though. The following works, is that the recommended way of doing this? Feels a bit cumbersome

```
val predicate = JsQueryPredicate<SportEvent>(query)
schedule.sport_events.filter { predicate.test(it) }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a method reference, which gets converted implicitly to a `(T) -> Boolean` and thus allows you to call the `filter` method:

```
schedule.sport_events.filter(predicate::test)
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer it more directly: yes... `predicate.test(it)` or the nearly equivalent method reference `predicate::test` are the way to go... except...

If you have to deal with Java predicates more often and/or the refactoring of the Java functional types (e.g. `Predicate`) to Kotlin function types is planned in future, you may also want to add appropriate extension functions instead, e.g.:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.filter(predicate: Predicate<T>) = filter { predicate.test(it) }
```

With the following usage then:

```
val javaPredicate : Predicate<String> = Predicate { it == "hello" }
listOf("hello", "world")
        .filter(javaPredicate)
```

If you replaced the `Predicate` in future to, e.g. `(T) -> Boolean` you then don't need to adapt that filter, but just replace/remove the import statement to the extension function.

Extension functions to just transform the `Predicate` to an appropriate Kotlin function type are possible too, but may not help you that much in future refactorings:

```
operator fun <T> Predicate<T>.invoke() : (T) -> Boolean = ::test
fun <T> Predicate<T>.transform() : (T) -> Boolean = ::test
```

Usage samples of those:

```
val javaPredicate : Predicate<String> = Predicate { it == "hello" }

// variant with Predicate.invoke:
listOf("hello", "world")
    .filter(javaPredicate())

// variant using Predicate.transform()
listOf("hello", "world")
    .filter(javaPredicate.transform())
```

So I recommend you the overloaded `filter`-method in case you plan a refactoring or otherwise just stick to `filter { predicate.test(it) }`/`filter(predicate::test)`, which might make a future refactoring a bit (IDEs help ;-)) harder.